# Button tag not working with Dynamic Value in a loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, for-loop, tags

Kindly check my code:

```
for (i = 0; i < fifth_img.count; i++)
{
    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    aButton.frame     = CGRectMake(xCord, yCord + space,buttonWidth,buttonHeight);
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whatever1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [aButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    aButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:0.0];

    aButton.tag = i;
    [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[fifth_img objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [seasonsScrollView addSubview:aButton];
    yCord += buttonHeight + space;
}
[seasonsScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(Vu_leftPanel.frame.size.width, yCord)];
[Vu_leftPanel addSubview:seasonsScrollView];


for( int b=0; b<6; b++){
    [(UIButton *)[Vu_leftPanel viewWithTag:b] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[fifth_img objectAtIndex:b]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

When i put 5 or 3 or 1 in viewWithTag:5 it's working but when i put just b, the app crash.

Comment: i also have tried (long)b

Comment: Can you please display more code?

Comment: What is printed in console at crash?

Comment: Can you please tell the Error that you're getting..

Comment: @NimitParekh please check the code... and i just get that only 0 value is giving me error all other values of b are working fine.

Comment: Is Vu_leftPanel has another view which tag is zero?

Comment: All views have a 0 tag as a default so if you get a 0 view it could be any view, according to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540012/uiview-viewwithtag-0-problem

Comment: It'd be nice if you can share the log as well? And are you sure you have 6 buttons and not 5?

Comment: only this: viewWithTag:0 giving me error .... all are working fine...

Comment: Please rewrite your both for loops with i = 1, i <= ing.count. It will work.

Comment: @AliAB. Thanks mate, that worked. I just started tags of button from 1. like, i+1 and now its working fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int xCord = 0;
    int yCord = 0;
    int space = 5;
    int buttonWidth = 25;
    int buttonHeight = 25;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        aButton.frame     = CGRectMake(xCord, yCord + space,buttonWidth,buttonHeight);
        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whatever1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [aButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        aButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:0.0];

        aButton.tag = 1000 + i;
        [aButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",1000 + i] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[fifth_img objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [seasonsScrollView addSubview:aButton];
        yCord += buttonHeight + space;
    }
for( int b=0; b<6; b++){
        [(UIButton *)[Vu_leftPanel viewWithTag:1000 - b] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[fifth_img objectAtIndex:b]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

Comment: did you removed tag line in above text? just replace i with i+1 in above loop and viewWithTag:b+1 in blow loop... that worked

Comment: @NasirKhan never to use tag start with 0, if you create any long int as a tag start value then it's much more clarify the view tags.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that  Vu_leftPanel does not have any other view with the tag between 0 and 6 **[As the default tag for the views is 0]**. As setBackgroundImage: forState: method can only be called on UIButton.
If any other view receives this method call, then app will crash with unrecognized selector sent to instance exception.

Try setting the tags from 1000 to 1006. And then try setting the background image.

Comment: Good answer, maybe you should precise that the view's default tag value is 0. So the viewWithTag:0 doesn't necessary returns a UIButton.